# Why does vector sum $(x_1,x_2)+'(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+2y_1, 3x_2-y_2)$ and $(cx_1,cx_2)$ fail to hold the axiom of vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Why does vector sum $(x_1,x_2)+'(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+2y_1, 3x_2-y_2)$ and $c(x_1, x_2)=(cx_1,cx_2)$ fail to hold the axiom of vector space?

Is it because $(x+'y)+z=(x_1+2y_1, 3x_2-y_2)+(z_1, z_2)=(x_1,x_2)+(2y_1+z_1, -y_2+z_2)\ne x+(y+z)$

But I don't see how this is not right. Could anyone point out what is wrong here?

Comment: You should not mix ordinary vector addition with the vector operation +'.  Check if $(\mathbf x +' \mathbf y) +' \mathbf z = \mathbf x +' (\mathbf y +' \mathbf z)$. That is not what you're doing.

Comment: I don't see how $+'$ generally works

Comment: You gave us a *formula* for it!  So it "works" by using it: substitute in actual numbers for the coordinates on the left and the formula on the right tells you what it is.  Do you not see how the function $f(a,b) = a+3b$ "works"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed associativity fails. But it is easier to show that commutativity fails, that in general we do not have $u+'v=v+'u$.

Let $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$. Then $u+'v=(1,-1)$ and $v+'u=(2,3)$.

Answer (score 2):

One of the [axioms of vector spaces](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html) is associativity of vector addition. Thus, $(x+y)+z=x+(y+z)$ must be true in order for this to be a vector space. Let $x=(x_1, x_2)$, $y=(y_1, y_2)$, and $z=(z_1, z_2)$.

$$(x+y)+z=(x_1+2y_1, 3x_2-y_2)+(z_1, z_2)=(x_1+2y_1+2z_1, 3(3x_2-y_2)-z_2)=(x_1+2y_1+2z_1, 9x_2-3y_2-z_2)$$
$$x+(y+z)=(x_1, x_2)+(y_1+2z_1, 3y_2-z_2)=(x_1+2(y_1+2z_1), 3x_2-(3y_2-z_2))=(x_1+2y_1+4z_1, 3x_2-3y_2+z_2)$$

As you can see, $(x+y)+z \neq x+(y+z)$, so this is not a vector space.

Comment: But how about $cx_1, cx_2$, does that not hold either?

Comment: I don't think anything's wrong with $c(x_1, x_2)=(cx_1, cx_2)$. However, for it to be a vector space, _all_ of the axioms must hold, not just some of them.

Comment: Well, suppose $c\cdot f=c+f$, how do you check associativity and commutativity? Do you find a new function or a new scalar?

Comment: I'm assuming $c$ and $f$ are scalars since you're multiplying them, so that doesn't give us a formula for vector addition for which we can check associativity and commutativity. To check associatvity and commutativity, you have to use the formula of vector addition given to you from the vector space.

Comment: what if it is $cf(x)$, I can only think of distributivity, but having no idea about associativity

Comment: You can only verify associativity with a rule for vector addition. $cf(x)$ is a rule for scalar multiplication, so you can't verify vector addition with that.

Comment: @Noble Mushtak, do you mind explaining the simple reasoning behind each of the equations you wrote under both (x+y) + z and x + (y+z) I think I probably have various misunderstandings, not really following how/why you came up with these 2 calculations?

Comment: @NobleMushtak I am having trouble understanding how you did this 1st step? (+)+=(1+21,32−2)+(1,2)=(1+21+21,3(32−2)−2)=(1+21+21,92−32−2) Why do you have x1+2y1+2z1, 3(3x2-y2)-z2? how did you get those?

Comment: @bernando_vialli I am using the definition of + given in the question. The question says $(x_1, x_2)+(y_1, y_2)=(x_1+2y_1, 3x_2-y_2)$, so in the last step, I substitute $x_1+2y_1$ in for $x_1$, $z_1$ in for $x_2$, $3x_2-y_2$ in for $y_1$ and $z_2$ in for $y_2$.