# Understanding Vector Spaces well

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I really want to get a strong grasp of abstract linear algebra for 2 reasons, I want to go deeper in pure mathematics for joy (abstract algebra, number theory etc) and to have a deeper understanding of how machine learning algorithms work under the hood.

I have been struggling with understanding vector spaces well. I have read through the axioms, their proofs and other examples/sample exercises on them in both textbooks as well as here on math stack exchange. When I look at the solutions both here and on some math stack exchange on why a certain object is a vector space or not, I don't follow the reasoning. Here is one such old question from here (this is just 1 example, there are many others I don't follow)

[Why does vector sum $(x_1,x_2)+'(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+2y_1, 3x_2-y_2)$ and $(cx_1,cx_2)$ fail to hold the axiom of vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625069/why-does-vector-sum-x-1-x-2y-1-y-2-x-12y-1-3x-2-y-2-and-cx-1-cx-2?rq=1)

When I looked at the very brief accepted answer that just states:

Let =(1,0) and =(0,1). Then +′=(1,−1) and +′=(2,3).

I don't understand how did they come up with (2,3)?

I looked at the 2nd solution which has a lot more detail and am quiet confused. It seems like the algebraic manipulations are done in a different way from what I would expect knowing high school algebra?

For example here (sorry still need to learn latex):

(+)+=(1+21,32−2)+(1,2)=(1+21+21,3(32−2)−2)=(1+21+21,92−32−2)

could someone explain to me how each of these equations are arrived at it detail? I don't understand why you can add a "+2z1" when it was just "z1" by itself? Also, in the following equation why can you do "3(32−2)" it seems like you are applying the 3 multiplier 2 times over? And the same reasoning I am missing from +(+) equation but I guess it would be similar.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, the definition says $(x_1, x_2)+'(y_1, y_2)=(x_1+2y_1, 3x_2-y_2)$, right?  So $(0,1)+'(1,0)=(0+2\times 1, 3\times 1 -0)=(2,3)$.

Comment: sorry for my stupid follow up questions, I am sure they are very basic. Firstly, why can you do "Let =(1,0) and =(0,1)", like what allows you do do that?  Also, is the reason you plug the 1 in (0+2X1) because (0,1) has the 1 in the y-coordinate? And the same reasoning I am guessing applied to (3X1 - 0) because here 1 is the x-coordinate?

Comment: In that example one wants to prove that it (with the given operations(!)) is *not* a vector space. They show that commutativity of the given operation fails by presenting a *specific example* where it indeed fails.

Comment: On the other hand, I'd suggest to try to rather build up your knowledge based on things that you already understand better. It's typical to keep getting stuck when you insist to follow something that you don't understand, and many times these are even unnecessary dead-ends.

Comment: I'm not sure where your confusion lies.  You are given a clear definition of the "addition" operation.  You should practice adding a few vectors using it.  Just pick them randomly, whatever you like.  In order to qualify as a vector space addition we'd need it to be commutative.  That's not enough but it is necessary.  Now, any one example in which $u+'v\neq v+'u$ proves it is not commutative hence that it can't be a vector space addition.  Nothing magical about the example the authors gave (though using the standard basis vectors is certainly a natural thing to try).

Comment: so can you try it on any vectors say =(5,0) and =(0,5) that are scalar multiples of (1,0) and (0,1)? Also, how do they come up with +′=(1,−1) in this example?

Comment: @lulu, I just want to understand where the +′=(1,−1) is coming from? I think aside from that I understand this example

Comment: If $(a, b) +' (c,d) = (a + 2c, 3b-d)$, then $(1,0) +' (0,1) = (1 + 2\cdot 0, 3\cdot0 - 1)= (1,-1)$. You can try it on any vectors your heart desires.

Comment: @user37496, why in this case can you assume that the first variable a is taken by the x coordinate and the 2nd variable c taken by y?

Comment: @bernando_vialli I don't understand your question. You are asking about how to compute $(1, 0) +' (0,1)$. That's the same as $(x_1, x_2) +' (y_1, y_2)$ with $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$, $y_1 = 0$, and $y_2 = 1$. Then you just plug these numbers into the given definition of $+'$.

Comment: yes I understand the how, I am trying to understand the why, meaning that why is it (1)+(2)*(0) instead of 0 + (2)*(1)? Why do we replace the a with the x-coordinate 1 instead of the y coordinate 0 and the c with the y coordinate 0 instead of the x coordinate 1?

Comment: @bernando_vialli Because that's what the formula says to do. The formula says the components of the resultant vector are $x_1 + 2 y_1$ and $3 x_2 - y_2$. $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the components of the first vector in the $+'$ operation and $y_1$ and $y_2$ the components of the second vector. I have to admit to being quite mystified at your confusion, since the formula you wrote down is straightforward, and it's just a matter of applying it literally.

Comment: @user37496, I guess I am still not fully understanding in my mind what (1,2)+′(1,2)=(1+21,32−2)  is and why you need to test whether it's associative by plugging in (1,0 ) and (0,1) and why you can't just say that (x1+2y1) + (3x2 - y2) = (3x2 - y2) + (x1+2y1) and hence they are associative? I get the mechanics done but i think i am missing the understanding piece. Like in my mind I guess I am viewing it as an algebraic expression a + b + c + d with real numbers asking if it's associative and of course (a+b)+(c+d) = (c+d)+(a+b) so i don't get why it's different?

Comment: @bernando_vialli (1) The point is to show that this operation is not *commutative*. An operation $\star$ is commutative if $a \star b = b \star a$ for all $a$ and $b$. In this example, someone has constructed an operation $+'$ that has been very specifically chosen not to be commutative. We can show that it's not commutative by finding two vectors (any two we want) for which $a +' b \neq b +' a$. In this example, the vectors chosen to test this with happen to be the $u$ and $v$ in your post, but other examples would work as well .

Comment: (2) This is **not** an algebraic operation applied to real numbers. The objects to which we are applying this operation are two-dimensional *vectors*, not real numbers. These vectors have multiple components or entries. For example, the first component of the vector $u = (1,0)$ is 1, and the second component is $0$. The operation $+'$ takes two vectors $x=(x_1, x_2)$ and $y = (y_1, y_2)$ and produces a vector $z = (z_1, z_2)$ with components $z_1 = x_1 + 2 y_1$ and $z_2 = 3 x_2 - y_2$. These components are *not* added as in your expression $x_1 + 2y_1 + 3 x_2 - y_2$. They are separate entries.

Comment: (3) Read in English, the operation $+'$ says "To produce the first component of $x$ +' $y$, take the first component of the $x$ and add it to two times the first component of $y$. To produce the second component of $x$ +' $y$, take three times the second component of $x$ and subtract from it the second component of $y$." Again, the reason we're doing this is because this a specially constructed example designed to be non-commutative. This is not an operation we usually do with vectors, it's just meant to help you learn the axioms of a vector space and how to check whether or not they hold.

Comment: @user37496, I guess one thing I am having a hard time wrapping my head around is understanding the object of a vector space and it's axioms, like I am having a hard time picturing in my mind as to what it actually is and I think these examples confuse me because I can't grasp my mind as to how to think about a vector space

Comment: @bernando_vialli Are you familiar with vector from another context? I'm a physicist by training, and I got started learning about vectors in physics classes. In physics, vectors are used to describe pretty concrete things like velocity and force, and often you can just think of them as arrows in a two-dimensional plane ($\mathbf{R}^2$). I think the intuition you get from thinking about vectors in $\mathbf{R}^2$ goes a long way toward helping understand abstract vector spaces. The axioms of a vectors space essentially formalize that intuition.

Comment: @user37496 yes I am familiar with the context of vectors as arrows in 2d coming from physics, but I don't understand the relationship of those with the axioms of a vector space. Say you have vectors (1,2) and (2,3) I can picture those I guess from a physics perspective that you talk about as arrows going from (0,0) to these respective points. What I don't really understand from here is ok these are 2 vectors in my example. Do they form a vector space? What is the vector space in this example? What does associativity or commutativity of addition mean in this context, etc

Comment: @bernando_vialli  No, the two vectors don't form a vector space. The vector space in question would be $R^2$, the real two-dimensional plane. Every $(x, y)$ would be a vector in that space. Associativity means that when adding three vectors $u$, $v$, $w$, $u + (v + w) = (u + v) + w$. You can verify this holds for the "arrow picture" of vectors by picking three vectors (arrows) in the plane and adding them using the graphical method for vector addition (what I learned as the "tip-to-tail" method)....

Comment: ... if you first add $v + w$, then add that to $u$, it's the same as first adding $u + v$, then adding to $w$. Commutativity means the order of addition doesn't matter, $u + v = v + u$. Again, you can verify this for arrows using the graphical method of addition. (An example is here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelogramLaw.html). I would suggest trying to understand all of the axioms of a vector space in terms of arrows before moving on to understanding abstract vector spaces. A lot of the axioms will seem obvious when interpreted as statements about arrows in the plane ....

Comment: ... but that's because they're supposed to! They're just formalizing what we already know about how vectors work.

Comment: @user37496, ok what you are wrote now does make sense to me and that was how i pictured the concept before but I then fail to understand how does the example I put in this original post referencing the other link enter the picture on a conceptual level:  As long as you add any 2 vectors should form a vector in 2 dimensional space right? Since any (n, n) and (x,x) when added together will be some (n+x, n+x) vector? I guess I conceptually dont really understand what is an example of the axiom not holding since in my mind any 2 arrows that you add will always total some 3rd vector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119782/discussion-between-user37496-and-bernando-vialli).

Answer (score 1):

Normal vector addition is defined so that, given two (two-dimensional) vectors $\vec x = (x_1, x_2)$ and $\vec y = (y_1, y_2)$, their sum $\vec x + \vec y = (x_1, x_2) + (y_1, y_2)$ is defined to be equal to $(x_1 + y_1,\ x_2 + y_2)$. In other words, $$(x_1, x_2) + (y_1, y_2) \overset{\rm def}{=} (x_1 + y_1,\ x_2 + y_2).$$

(Note that the $+$ sign on the left side of the $\overset{\rm def}{=}$ symbol is really *a new operation* that we're defining, since we haven't previously defined what it means to add two vectors together.  The two $+$ signs on the right, however, simply denote the ordinary addition of two numbers.)

Now, the question asks what would happen if we were to define this new *vector addition operator* differently.  To avoid confusing this alternative definition with the normal one given above, let's denote the alternative addition operator by a different symbol.  The question uses $+'$ for this new operator, but I don't really like that choice for typographical reasons (the apostrophe looks too disconnected from the plus sign), so let me call it $\oplus$ instead.  Thus, our alternative vector addition rule now looks like this: $$(x_1, x_2) \oplus (y_1, y_2) \overset{\rm def}{=} (x_1 + 2y_1,\ 3x_2 - y_2).$$

Now, the question is whether the set $\mathbb R^2$, equipped with the usual vector multiplication operator $\cdot$ and this new alternative addition operator $\oplus$, could also satisfy the [definition of a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) over $\mathbb R$.

As it turns out, the answer is "no."  And to prove that, all we need to do is give at least one example of vectors for which at least one of the axioms in the definition of a vector space fails to hold.

Now, one of these axioms is that vector addition needs to be commutative: if $+$ denotes the addition operator in a vector space, then $\vec x + \vec y$ needs to always be equal to $\vec y + \vec x$.  Clearly this axiom does hold for the usual addition operator, as defined at the top of this answer.  Does it also hold for the alternative operator $\oplus$?

A moment's thought should reveal that it does not, since $x_1 + 2y_1$ is generally not equal to $y_1 + 2x_1$.  (In fact, the two expressions are only equal if $x_1 = y_1$.)  And, for that matter, $3x_2 - y_2$ is also not equal to $3y_2 - x_2$ unless $x_2 = y_2$.

So this alternative addition operator $\oplus$ in fact fails the commutativity requirement just about as badly as it's possible to fail it: $\vec x \oplus \vec y \ne \vec y \oplus \vec x$ whenever $\vec x \ne \vec y$.

But, as I noted earlier, we don't actually need to prove that this commutativity failure occurs for *all* pairs of non-equal vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.  All we need to do is show *one* pair of vectors for which it fails to hold.  So let's just pick any two distinct vectors — say, $\vec x = (0,1)$ and $\vec y = (1,0)$ — and do the arithmetic:

$$\begin{alignat}{3}
\vec x \oplus \vec y &=\;& (0,1) \oplus (1,0) &=\;& (0 + 2 \cdot 1,\ 3 \cdot 1 - 0) &= (2,3) \\
\vec y \oplus \vec x &=\;& (1,0) \oplus (0,1) &=\;& (1 + 2 \cdot 0,\ 3 \cdot 0 - 1) &= (1,-1).
\end{alignat}$$

Of course, you could just as well pick any other pair of distinct vectors.  And of course it doesn't matter whether you call the example vectors $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ or $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ or whatever.  And it also doesn't really matter whether you write your vector symbols as $\vec x$ or $\bar x$ or $\mathbf x$ or just $x$, although you should generally try to follow whichever convention your textbook uses.

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. Sorry for my late comment, unfortunately I don't get to think about linear algebra nearly as often as I would like. Can you be so kind as to explain the why behind why it works like this. One of my problems with these vector space examples seems to be that I don't have a good grasp in my mind of what the vector space object and it's axioms represent and how these rules come out of it? Like whether say an example is some n-dimentsional object say a 3 dimensional cube as long as long as part of the cube passes through the origin?

Comment: That might be worth asking as a separate follow-up question. I could try to answer it here (although I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to ask), but I think that would basically amount to a whole new answer. And with a new question, you'll get more eyeballs on it than just mine.

Comment: basically I am trying to understand in my head how to picture this object, vector space in my head, sort of in the same way that it's say easy to picture a triangle by drawing a basic picture on a piece of paper, or say the cartesian plane with lines say like y = 3x+2 you can easily graph with slope 3 and y intercept 2. I don't really understand how to picture a vector space in my mind, sort of like a picture of it in a sense