# Are groups and rings more difficult algebraic structures to understand than vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, soft-question

I have read multiple posts on here and in other places where most people seem to recommend to learning linear algebra before abstract algebra. Is that because vector spaces are simpler to understand than groups and rings? I am having some challenges with understanding how certain aspects of vector spaces work, I was wondering if learning about rings and/or groups can help me better understand how vector spaces work?

Comment: Out of curiosity, would you provide an example of a concept about vector spaces that you are finding difficult to understand?  If you were to say, "tensor products" or "determinants" or "minimal polynomials" then I might enthusiastically say, yes, algebra would give you some nice perspective.  If you said you're confused by SVD or numerical diagonalization, I might be less enthusiastic about you learning a lot of algebra (though algebra is an awesome subject and worth studying in its own right!).

Comment: This question is likely too opinion-based to be really good for this site, but I don't think that generic vector spaces are really any harder to understand than abstract groups or rings (indeed, a vector space is a module over a field, so maybe it is harder to understand abstractly?). However, most linear algebra classes deal specifically with vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, so they are very concrete.

Comment: This is something that I just posted about earlier today that I am still struggling to fully understand (it's a reference to another old post on finding whether something is or is not a vector space, I guess I still have not fully understood the subject well enough, I am confused on the answer to that question for example. When I have looked at questions on whether certain matrices are vector spaces or not, I don't always understand how to answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3880819/understanding-vector-spaces-well

Comment: also, how do they come up with: +′=(1,−1) in the example where I put up the link, I don't follow how they get it.

Comment: Calling (non-linear) algebra "abstract" is already a bias. For instance group theory, notably the study of permutation groups, can be "concretely" implemented, is natural in many combinatorial situations.

Comment: @YCor, can you explain what you mean?

Comment: It too long to elaborate in a comment, but I mean that calling some parts algebra "abstract algebra" (as is done in a few countries, and reflected in the MathSE tag [tag:abstract-algebra], some Wikipedia pages, etc) is not a neutral phrasing, and conveys the idea that it's more abstract than linear algebra, which I believe is false.

Comment: This is not a universal truth. Some people will find groups and rings simpler than vector spaces.

But there is a reason why people say that: more structure tends to bring more "order". Vector spaces are very structured compared to groups; and they are very structured compared to rings (which isn't the right comparison, we should be talking about modules).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, do you think in the instance that the person finds groups and rings simpler then vector spaces they should take abstract algebra before linear algebra?

Comment: @bernando_vialli: I think you should follow the curriculum set by your professors. Especially if you're studying with friends (which you should do in general). I also think most books in algebra will assume you've read some linear algebra for their basic examples, in case you want to study on your own.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am mostly just self studying, not taking any courses now as I work full time in data analytics/science...

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Your understanding is correct. There is a theorem that any two finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces (vector spaces defined over the field $k$) of the same dimension are isomorphic:
$$ \dim(V_1) = \dim(V_2) = n < \infty \implies V_1 \simeq V_2 \simeq k^n.$$
However, this is not the case for groups and rings. In fact, two finitely generated abelian groups may have the same rank but not be isomorphic: the obvious example is in rank 0, considering the Klein four group
$$
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \not\simeq \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}.
$$
(Recall that finitely generated abelian groups may be expressed in the form
$$
 G = \mathbb{Z}^r \oplus G_{\text{tors}}
$$
where $r$ is the rank and the torsion part $G_{\text{tors}}$ is finite.)

And that is just in the finitely generated abelian case! Loosening these assumptions, there are far more possibilities to contend with. So it makes sense to start by studying the simpler case of linear algebra.

Comment: The main challenge is in understanding linear maps, though

Answer (score 7):

Yes, generally speaking vector spaces are particulary simple algebraic structures. Therefore, they make a fine introduction to more advanced aspects of Abstract Algebra.

For instance, if you are working with vector spaces over, say, the real numbers, and if $v$ is a vector, then you never have$$\overbrace{v+v+\cdots+v}^{n\text{ times}}=0\tag1$$(unless $v=0$). Over some other fields (say, finite fields), there is a natural number $n$ such that you *always* have $(1)$. In a group (or a ring), you can have $(1)$ for certain elements and certain $n$'s, whereas for other elements you don't have $(1)$, no matter which $n$ you choose.

And every vector space has a basis. The natural generlization of vector spaces over a fields are modules over a ring. And these seldom have a basis.

Furthermore, there is a very simple classification of all vector spaces over a filed: up to isomorphism, for each cardinal there is one and only one vector space whose dimension is that cardinal. There's nothing similar for grous or rings.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry for my silly question what does it mean that expression is not equal to 0 unless v = 0? Not sure that I understand that

Comment: Your example with $v+\dotsb+v = 0$ is fine if you are working over a field of characteristic zero (as you say, $\mathbb{R}$ is an example), but does not hold in general.  This seems to be an argument in favor of working first with $\mathbb{R}$ (and subgroups thereof, and ideals therein, and vector spaces over).  This does *not* seem to me to be an argument in favor of first working with abstract vector spaces before working with other abstract algebraic structures.

Comment: @bernando_vialli On a real vector space, if $v\ne 0$, that $v+v+\cdots+v$ is never equal to $0$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson On a vector space $V$, either $v\ne0\implies(\forall n\in\Bbb N):nv=0$ or $(\exists n\in\Bbb N)(\forall v\in V):nv=0$, depending on the type of field that we are working with. On an abstract algebraic structure, things are more complex than this.

Answer (score 4):

Linear algebra can be viewed with some advanced algebraic tools; for example a vector space can be thought of as an abelian group paired with an additional operation of scalar multiplication. We can consider vector spaces over finite fields. Matrices can be viewed as providing homomorphisms between vector spaces. Furthermore, groups of invertible matrices provide important examples of nonabelian groups.

On the other hand, a first introduction to linear algebra can be given without looking too deeply at the algebraic machinery. Students don't need to learn really any group theory or field theory to consider vector addition over the real or complex numbers. We can teach students about linear maps between vector spaces without going too deeply into the concept of homomorphisms between algebraic structures.

In short, linear algebra before "abstract algebra" is often recommended because an introductory look at linear algebra provides a good first look at concepts that will come up in a more advanced algebra course. It is particularly nice to teach students about nonabelian groups when they are already familiar with matrix multiplication, as this allows lots of interesting examples to be presented early on in the course.

**BUT:** Linear algebra is a really beautiful and deep subject. There are lots of cool advanced topics that can be covered once you are familiar with some advanced topics in algebra. So it is definitely worth coming back and taking a second course in linear algebra once you do understand groups, rings, fields, modules, homomorphisms, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I learned group theory and ring theory before learn about vector spaces and linear algebra in general. As I see these three subjects built for three different purposes, at least at the beginning. Group theory to study general solutions of algebraic equations (basically Galois theory), ring theory for solutions of system of polynomial equations (algebraic geometry), and linear algebra for solutions of system of linear equations. So, while being algebraic theories, they have different structures and different flavors. Of course learning any of theses first would be beneficial to understand the other, but I won't say one is particularly simple or interesting than others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  There is a certain amount of overlap, and both subjects range from difficult and complicated to simple and trivial.

For one or two examples, a vector space can be viewed as an abelian group with some additional structure. Furthermore, any abelian group is a $\Bbb Z$-module.   And, any field is a vector space over its prime subfield.

I noticed that there is at least one book that treats both subjects simultaneously.  *Linear Algebra and Group Theory*, by V.I. Smirnov.